# Recieving JSON with null fields

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an API (just for study), when I try to list files saved on my DB (local) using endpoint to list the files, I'm recieving this:

```
[
{
    "nome": null,
    "url": null,
    "type": null,
    "size": 0,
    "paciente": null,
    "medico": null
}
```

]

this is my endpoint:

```
    @GetMapping("/files")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ResponseFile>> getListFiles() {
        List<ResponseFile> files = resultadosExamesService.listarTodosArquivos().map(dbFile -> {
            String fileDownloadUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                    .fromCurrentContextPath()
                    .path("/exames/files/")
                    .path(dbFile.getIdExame().toString())
                    .toUriString();

            return new ResponseFile(
                    dbFile.getNomeArquivo(),
                    fileDownloadUri,
                    dbFile.getTipoExame(),
                    dbFile.getArquivoExame().length);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(files);
    }
```

and my ResponseFile:

```
public class ResponseFile {
    private String nome;
    private String url;
    private String type;
    private long size;
    private Paciente paciente;

    private PacientesDTO pacienteDTO;
    private Medico medico;

    public ResponseFile(String nomeArquivo, String fileDownloadUri, String tipoExame, int length) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.url = url;
        this.type = type;
        this.size = size;

    }
//get and set...
```

I was expecting to recieve a JSON like this:
(this endpoint lists doctor's appointments from DB)

```
[
{
    "idConsulta": 2,
    "nomeMedico": "Camila Bernardo",
    "nomePaciente": "João",
    "motivoConsulta": "fortes dores de cabeça",
    "dataConsulta": "2023-12-12T14:00:00"
},
{
    "idConsulta": 3,
    "nomeMedico": "Camila Bernardo",
    "nomePaciente": "João",
    "motivoConsulta": "fortes dores de cabeça",
    "dataConsulta": "2023-12-12T16:00:00"
}
```

]

Comment: I suspect the problem is that `dbFile` is returning null/default values. What is the mapping there?

Comment: @Shadow It's mapped by the entity

Comment: `
@Entity
@Table(name = "RESULTADOS_EXAMES")
public class ResultadosExames {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_exame")
    private Integer idExame;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PACIENTE_FK")
    private Paciente idPaciente;

    @Column(name = "TIPO_EXAME")
    private String tipoExame;

    @Column(name = "DATA_EXAME")
    private LocalDate dataExame;

    @Column (name = "NOME_ARQUIVO")
    private String nomeArquivo;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "ARQUIVO_EXAME")
    private byte[] arquivoExame;`

Comment: Don't post more than one line of code in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Your ResponseFile has null values, because the dbFile has empty values. Do deeper. Learn to use a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

If I am not wrong, your problem occurs due to ResponseFile. I think ResponseFile should not look like that, it should look more like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cashes")
public class Cash {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  int id;

  @Column(name="storecode")
  int storeCode;

  @Column(name="storecashcode")
  int storeCashCode;

  @Column(name="generatedtoken")
  String generatedToken;

  @Column(name="usage")
  int usage;

  public Cash(int id, int storeCode, int storeCashCode, String generatedToken,
        int usage) {
      this.id = id;
      this.storeCode = storeCode;
      this.storeCashCode = storeCashCode;
      this.generatedToken = generatedToken;
      this.usage = usage;
  }

  public Cash() {}

  //getters and setters
```

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name = "RESULTADOS_EXAMES")
public class ResultadosExames {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_exame")
    private Integer idExame;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PACIENTE_FK")
    private Paciente idPaciente;

    @Column(name = "TIPO_EXAME")
    private String tipoExame;

    @Column(name = "DATA_EXAME")
    private LocalDate dataExame;

    @Column (name = "NOME_ARQUIVO")
    private String nomeArquivo;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "ARQUIVO_EXAME")
    private byte[] arquivoExame;`

Comment: I have the entity and the response file shold acess it to get the JSON mapped. I've created the entity for the file as well